# visual studio: tell in part of the code to don't exception-break when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am debugging exceptions in my code, and I my debugger is set to break when one comes out.

I would like my debugging session to exception-break on a certain part of my code and not another, do you know il there is an argument (or other) I could write in my code to tell the debugger to don't exception-break on this part of code?

The exceptions I debug are API'exceptions with the same type, I can't filter them by type.

Thx

ps: please be advised that I know "Debug / Exception" but this is useless in my case as I don't want to filtrer a certain type of exception, only filter them in a part of the code.

Example:

```
#region don't want to break at exception
Try
{
  //I don't want the debugger to break here
  ApiMethodThatThrowException();
}
Catch(Exception){}
#endregion
#region want to break at exception
Try
{
  //I want the debugger to break here
  ApiMethodThatThrowException();
}
Catch(Exception){}
#endregion
```

Comment: Set/un-set break points in the debugger?

Comment: Oh damned, I was talking about exception breaks, i'll edit my question

Comment: Hit F5 and keep going.

Comment: sorry, I was talking about exception-breaks

Comment: You can certainly choose which exceptions to break on, and which to pass over. No idea whether you can choose areas of the code to break / not break on.

Comment: It's still not really clear what you mean.  Maybe you can describe a specific scenario?  The Visual Studio debugger has options to stop when certain kinds of exceptions are thrown, but at a pretty high level.  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do without a concrete example, though.

Comment: I cant choose by type as my exceptions are API exceptions with the same type.

Comment: @David I added an example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @abelenky's answer, I'd like to note that there are certain `Exceptions` that Visual Studio won't let you disable (`C++ Exceptions`, `GPU Memory Access Exceptions`, etc). You then have to look at using the `System.Diagnostics` attributes to bypass these `Exceptions` in the debugger.

[DebuggerHiddenAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerhiddenattribute.aspx) and [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) are two of the attributes that can be used to tell the debugger to skip certains sections of code.

```
public string ConnectionString{
    [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    get { 
        // Implementation here; 
    }
}
```

Above example taken from:
[Using Attributes to Improve the Quality..](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/391/using-attributes-to-improve-the-quality-and-usability-of-your-code-part-2-improving-debugging)

```
[DebuggerHiddenAttribute]
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Implementation here;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I needed this for a logout button in a web app, tired to seeing ThreadAbortExceptions when calling Response.End in a Try Catch Do nothing block

Comment: VS2015, the exception still throws but points at the calling routine.  There's no Regex.TryParse, I'm dealing with user-entered filters, I'm very tired of this!

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual Studio Menus, go to:

**Debug / Exceptions...**

In that dialog, you can select when the Debugger should break for each kind of exception.
You can select if it should break when the exception is first thrown, or when it goes unhandled.
You can also add new kinds of exceptions to break (or not break) on.

Here is **[an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** with more details

Comment: No I can't, as the exceptions are API exception with the same type. (And I do want to see them in some parts of the code)

Comment: I think the closest thing that @NicoC will be able to get is to use `DebuggerHiddenAttribute`.

Comment: @Bob thanks a lot! [DebuggerHidden] is the solution for me. Please add your comment as response, I'll tag it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

From where the error is going, make sure to use the `try` and `catch` operators.

Where-ever your broken code is, you can simply do the following:

```
try {
  // Code here
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

This will prevent Visual Studio from popping out the error in the middle of the process.

Comment: I can't do that as I want to see them when thrown. And my debugger is set to break at those, even if there is TryCatch

Comment: Then make sure to use the e value, for example, Console.WriteLine(e.toString());

Comment: I'm displaying exception at the line of the exception, TryCatch won't change this behavior, whatever I do with the exception catched by TryCatch.